# error al genera PDF con dompdf

Tags: php

Cordial saludo.

En estos momentos estoy probando el funcionamiento de dompdf, ya que deseo incluir la descarga de documentos pdf en mi sitio web.

Lo primero que hice fue descarga la librería dompdf de esta url: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/releases/tag/v1.0.2

Luego de ponerla en la carpeta de mi sitio web, trate de probarlo con este código `php` (mi version `php` es la 7.2.24):

```
<?php ob_start();?>
<h2>ingenio</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>nombre</td>
        <td>apellido</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Josue Juan</td>
        <td>Quinzapa</td>
    </tr>
</table>
 
<?php
require_once 'dompdf/autoload.inc.php';
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf=new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html(ob_get_clean());
$dompdf->render();
$pdf=$dompdf->output();
$filename="nombre.pdf";
file_put_contents($filename,$pdf);
$dompdf->stream($filename);
?>
```

pero al tratar de verlo en mi sito web, me sale este error:

> Fatal error:
> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Dompdf\mb_internal_encoding() in /var/www/html/analistaflota/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php:323 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/analistaflota/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php(295): Dompdf\Dompdf->setPhpConfig() #1 /var/www/html/analistaflota/abc.php(17): Dompdf\Dompdf->__construct() #2 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/analistaflota/dompdf/src/Dompdf.php on line 323

Agradezco me ayuden para identificar mi problema.